# Async is considered a syntactic error in 3.6.2

Tags: python, python-asyncio, discord

Recently, I've been creating a Discord bot with python and have been following some guides. However, despite upgrading to Python 3.6.2 and including the asyncio library, this block of code is considered a syntactic error:

```
import discord
import asyncio
import secret

komorebi = Bot(command_prefix="!")

@komorebi.event()
async def on_read(): #syntax error
   print("Client is Online.")
```

I don't know if pyenv is to blame as I just recently installed it, but I stated "pyenv local 3.6.2" in the correct directory and "python -V" displays "Python 3.6.2". I have also installed discord.py, which appeared to be an error in another person's case. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If there’s a syntax error pointing to `async` it means that you’re running a different version of python than you expected. How did you ran the script?

Comment: Try step-by-step in python console, and, please, provide the error message.

Comment: Unrelated, but did you mean `on_ready()` instead of `on_read()`? The latter is not a valid event name, but you use it in your post...

Comment: @abccd : I ran the script using 'python bot.py'. I also tried 'python3 bot.py'.    
                However, that did not work as well. I completely revamped my 
                code and now it is functioning perfectly (using python3 bot.py).

Comment: @SergeyBelash : Oddly enough, there wasn't an error message in the 
                             python console. I typically use 'python' to execute my 
                             programs, but 'python3 bot.py' did the trick!

Comment: @squaswin : Good looks! That was definitely a typo. Thanks!